# Android FragmentTabHost Layout Positioning

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I am learning Android development and I am trying to make a tab interface inside a fragment, with the tabs in the bottom. I have seen many web pages ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745438/how-do-you-put-fragmenttabhost-on-bottom)) about how to configure the tabs to be in the bottom using a `RelativeLayout` but I can't get things right in the screen.

The tab's `FrameLayout` is taking all the space for the tab interface, and the tabs can't be seen:

[image: tabs not being shown]

The code I am using is:

```
        <android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibRight"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ibRight"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibRight"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ibTop">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

Just as a quick test, I adjusted the `FrameLayout` width and height to be fixed (500dp and 200dp), and that's what I got:

[image: Tab with tabs]

So this way I can see that all things are there, but I can't get it to be shown right, without playing with fixed width and height numbers. AND the fact that Android Studio has a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370745/fragmenttabhost-graphical-layout-doesnt-render) which causes a null reference for rendering for FragmentTabLayout make things even harder to play with, since I can't test option in real time.

I appreciate if anyone can help me with this, since I new to Android, I am not quite sure how to get this done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it to work with the following code:

```
        <android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ibBannerRight"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ibBannerRight"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ibBannerRight"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ibBannerTop">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v13.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

The secret ingredient was the `android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"`

Now everything seems fine:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please put the tabs on the top in Android. This is not iOS

Comment: Exactly, this is not iOS, which means I am free to do it as I like, not as Apple likes it, nor as Google likes it, but the way I LIKE IT. And guess what, for my particular application the tabs have to go in the bottom (I have good reasons for this, since it's a kiosk system) it's good to be free :)

Comment: mFeinstein, there is no need to be rude, Mark has a point. You should do things accordingly to a guideline. It's not mandatory, but it will help your users to better understand your application!

Comment: I guess in the Internet makes it hard to understand the tone of one's voice... I was writing it quickly over my phone if I remember, I didn't meant to be rude at all.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: this application had to look unrelated to the technology behind it, and since it will be positioned in a kiosk, higher on a wall, placing the tabs on the top will make it more difficult for short people and children. And no, we couldn't put it in a better height, I wish we could.